# What drivers should I install after formatting a PC?

Tags: laptop, drivers, format, dell-vostro

I have Dell Vostro 3559 laptop and I am going to format it tomorrow.

What drivers should I install after formatting my laptop?

[In the official site](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/vostro-15-3559-laptop/drivers), I can find more then 40 drivers. Do I need to download and install of of them?

If not, what are I need to install?

Comment: Install all of them. Or else you're going to end up with a non-functional trackpad, a blank screen, or worse.

Comment: @user96931 All of them? I mean 40+?

Comment: Install Quickset First! or other drivers will not install properly.

Comment: Also turn on "Show downloads by Service Tag for factory-installed components" then enter your service tag to only show downloads for your specific model.

Comment: @Damith, while 40+ sounds like a lot, read their names. They are for things such as SATA hard drive compatibility, bluetooth, etc. Download the ones applicable (for example, if one is for a hard drive you don't have, skip it -- most of the Serial ATA drivers you won't need) but if you're unsure about one, better download it.

Comment: I am going to contradict most people here... Just install Windows 10 and let install the drivers needed from Microsoft's update servers, then check Device Manager and see what isn't working properly and only install the ones necessary to get those devices working, if any... Many Dell and other OEM drivers are on Microsoft's servers, so why go through the "extra" steps.

Comment: When there are multiple drivers for the same hardware, look for the one which is the latest version (newest release date) and install those. A better option would be to first install the Ethernet and WiFi drivers so that you have internet connection upon installing Windows. Then you can use something like [Dell SupportAssist](https://www.dell.com/support/contents/us/en/04/article/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/software-and-downloads/supportassist) to find and automatically install the latest version of all other remaining drivers.

Comment: Agreed with @acejavelin with the exceptions: 1) It is possible that OS installer will not init disk controller drivers properly, so the device/volume for to instal onto will not be accessible. If so the disk controller drivers must be got and provided to OS installer during install OS; 2) it is possible that NIC drivers won't be installed/set properly so Windows Update won't be available. If so the NIC drivers must be get and provided to installed OS manually;

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to select correct OS, then:

**Install Quickset First!** or other drivers will not install properly.

Then turn on "Show downloads by Service Tag for factory-installed components" then enter your service tag to only show downloads for your specific model, Or use the **Detect Drivers** button if you have internet access on that Dell.